# Cannot declare a class extension in swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm using xcode 7 with swift version 2. I'm trying to follow on a tutorial in a swift tutorial but the code is written with swift 1.2

When I added a class extension block I got the error: Declaration is only valid at file scope. This is the extension block:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
        {
            // 1
            if let treasure = annotation as? Treasure {
            let view: MKPinAnnotationView
            // 2
            if let dequeueView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeueView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeueView
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.animatesDrop = false
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            }

            view.pinColor = treasure.pinColor()
            // 6
            return view
            }
            return nil
        }
```

I have no clue how to resolve this as I didn't work with protocols or extensions before. Should I write it differently using swift 2.0?

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


  @IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView!

    var treasures: [Treasure] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
                self.mapView.delegate = self
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.treasures)

        self.treasures = [
            HistoryTreasure(what: "Google's first office",
                            year: 1999,
                            latitude: 37.44451, longitude: -122.163369),
            HistoryTreasure(what: "Facebook's first office",
                            year: 2005,
                            latitude: 37.444268, longitude: -122.163271),
            FactTreasure(what: "Stanford University",
                        fact: "Founded in 1885 by Leland Stanford.",
                        latitude: 37.427474, longitude: -122.169719),
            FactTreasure(what: "Moscone West",
                        fact: "Host to WWDC since 2003.",
                        latitude: 37.783083, longitude: -122.404025),
            FactTreasure(what: "Computer History Museum",
                        fact: "Home to a working Babbage Difference Engine.", latitude: 37.414371, longitude: -122.076817),
            HQTreasure(company: "Apple",
                        latitude: 37.331741, longitude: -122.030333),
            HQTreasure(company: "Facebook",
                        latitude: 37.485955, longitude: -122.148555),
            HQTreasure(company: "Google",
                        latitude: 37.422, longitude: -122.084),
        ]



    }

    extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
        {
            // 1
            if let treasure = annotation as? Treasure {
            let view: MKPinAnnotationView
            // 2
            if let dequeueView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeueView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeueView
        } else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.animatesDrop = false
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            }

            view.pinColor = treasure.pinColor()
            // 6
            return view
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `MKMapViewDelegate` from your class declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Declaration is only valid at file scope

**Declaration**: is referring to your `extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate`

**is only valid**: so, impliedly, if you do as it says then your code will compile

**at file scope**: i.e. at the top level within your file only. Not within any other class, struct, etc.

You currently have your extension declared within the scope of your class. Extensions must be at file scope. So cut and paste the code from inside your class to outside your class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {


  @IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView!

    var treasures: [Treasure] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
                self.mapView.delegate = self
                self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.treasures)

        self.treasures = [
            HistoryTreasure(what: "Google's first office",
                            year: 1999,
                            latitude: 37.44451, longitude: -122.163369),
            HistoryTreasure(what: "Facebook's first office",
                            year: 2005,
                            latitude: 37.444268, longitude: -122.163271),
            FactTreasure(what: "Stanford University",
                        fact: "Founded in 1885 by Leland Stanford.",
                        latitude: 37.427474, longitude: -122.169719),
            FactTreasure(what: "Moscone West",
                        fact: "Host to WWDC since 2003.",
                        latitude: 37.783083, longitude: -122.404025),
            FactTreasure(what: "Computer History Museum",
                        fact: "Home to a working Babbage Difference Engine.", latitude: 37.414371, longitude: -122.076817),
            HQTreasure(company: "Apple",
                        latitude: 37.331741, longitude: -122.030333),
            HQTreasure(company: "Facebook",
                        latitude: 37.485955, longitude: -122.148555),
            HQTreasure(company: "Google",
                        latitude: 37.422, longitude: -122.084),
        ]



    }
} 


extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        // 1
        if let treasure = annotation as? Treasure {
        let view: MKPinAnnotationView
        // 2
        if let dequeueView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin") as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        dequeueView.annotation = annotation
        view = dequeueView
    } else {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.animatesDrop = false
        view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
        }

        view.pinColor = treasure.pinColor()
        // 6
        return view
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: so we could only do extension for a viewcontroller , only within the viewcontroller file.swift ... is that what you are saying?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and solution. It worked!

Comment: If you write an extension, then those methods become available on the class you attach them to. Apple's runtime doesn't have an idea of methods being available on one class, but only to a particular other class. Therefore it can't actually restrict an extension to the scope of only one class. So it doesn't want you to think that it is.